# How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, helpfile

I want to find out how one can install Ubuntu on a webbook using a usb. I tried to use an external CD drive, but its not detected by my webbook.

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu to 12.04.

Comment: Here is the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) of Ubuntu ISO. Scroll down and check out "Easy ways to switch to Ubuntu"

Comment: May I ask, why you want to upgrade to 12.04 and not the current LTS version 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this 2 ways:

1. If you really want to install from USB, then you should look [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
2. I believe that the CD was not detected, because it's not the primary booting device, you have to change the order from which your computer boots in the BIOS, which normally can be accessed by some function key (in my case pressing F2) when PC just starts, you should find on how to do everything you need to install from cd [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/)